# pandas convert column to ints not working

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove items from `dfA` that are in also in `dfB`.

Thing is that `dfA` is in object type so I am trying to convert to int.
Here is the code:

```
dfA = pd.read_excel('small_file.xlsx',header=None)
dfB = pd.read_csv('large_file.csv',header=None)

dfA = dfA.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
dfA[0] = pd.to_numeric(dfA[0],errors='coerce')
dfA = dfA.dropna()

# converting to int
dfA[0] = dfA[0].astype(int) # THIS line gets error


df_output = dfA[~dfA[0].isin(dfB[0])]
```

here is what dfA looks like

```
                0
0       2293365227
1       3045897298
2       8162414592
3       9312969810
...            ...
```

and dfB

```
               0
0          2030000000
1          2030156119
2          2030389149
...            ...
```

I get this error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'Goulding'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With errors like these, it's always good to take a closer look.

Use:

```
dfA.loc[dfA[0].str.contains('Goulding')]
```

To find the indices where this exists and see what's going on. Then create a function that filters out the bad data and apply it to the series. If you hit another error, rinse and repeat.

Example:

```
def replace_str(x):
     return re.search('\d+',x).group(0)

dfA[0] = dfA[0].apply(replace_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is some value - probably the string `'Goulding'`, which cannot be converted to int.

You can use to_numeric and get NaN where is problematic value:

`dfA[0] = pd.to_numeric(dfA[0], errors='coerce')`

prior to converting the whole column to ints.

If you could also share the excel file, I could take a closer look.